# Responsive input field and submit button using display:table-cell

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have the input field and the submit button stretch across the screen in the same row. Basically so the submit button does not ever go below the input field. Not even sure if I need to add an extra  or not. I know that I have seen a way to have a responsive input field and submit button using display:table-cell, but I have not been able to find it lately. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT

I added:  margin-left: -8px;  to the submit button and that did the trick. Not sure if there is a better way but this works. Any other ways would be appreciated as well.

```css
#div1{
  display:table;
  width:100%;
}
#div2{
  display:table-cell;
  
}
input[type="email"].form-control {
    width: 80%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
input[type="submit"].btn.btn-primary {
    width: 20%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-left: -8px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
        <div id="div2">
           <input type="email" name="EMAIL" class="form-control" 
            placeholder="Enter your E-mail Address">
           <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" class="btn btn-primary">
        </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: I just edited it and ran a code snippet and the subscribe button goes below the input field if the width is 20%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line feed between the two s creates a space between them on the page. You have to remove the line feed, or use this trick :

```
<input type="email" name="EMAIL" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your E-mail Address"><!--
--><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" class="btn btn-primary">
```

Also you have to remove border because it has 2px border so it's width is 20%+80%+ 2px+2px+2px+2px(left and right for two inputs)
use

```
border:0;
```

check this updates [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r2c8xLar/3/) please
Check this post [remove spaces between inputs](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Comment: 80% on the input field and 20% on the submit button should work, but it appears that there is a margin or something after the input field. That is why it goes to the next line with the submit button. And I have 0 for padding and margin so I know it is just something small I am missing.

Comment: Every browser gives a little margin between two input types. If you make
margin:-2px; that should work with 80% and 20%

Comment: That is link is pretty cool. It definitely solves the issue. But I think it just feels kinda weird to me. Thanks for the link though, I will keep this one on hand.

Comment: @PressAwesome check updated post please. I figured out why it doesn't fit there with 20% + 80% width

Comment: I am marking your answer as done. Thanks, really appreciated.

Comment: Thank you :) I have faced this problem earlier with spacing problem and i use a lot this trick.

Comment: You can simply put box-sizing: border-box instead of this hack, check my answer

Comment: There are many ways to make this you can simply make some margin:-2px; and it's fixed but i explained the problem here why it's happening and how it could be fixed. And you way works i know that and it's great that you posted because other people that will see this post can choose one from many options :) i will give thumbs up to your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you Trying to achieve something like this using display:table-cell ?

```
<div id="div2">
    <input type="email" name="EMAIL" class="form-control" 
    placeholder="Enter your E-mail Address">
    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" class="btn btn-primary">
```

```
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

#div2 {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

#div2 > * {
  display: table-cell;
}

   #div2 > input[type='email'] {
  width: 80%;
}

#div2 > input[type='submit'] {
  width: 20%;
}
```

the key is box-sizing: border-box; you can write it just for your desired elements

https://jsfiddle.net/uw4u6ta5/3/

Comment: Kinda, but I want the input field to be 80% and the submit button to be 20%.... but like on your example there is a space between the input field and the submit button

Comment: Hey I solved it using display table-cell updated the fiddle check it

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need two divs wrapping your inputs for this. You need to set the div to white-space: nowrap; to keep your inputs on one line. Simply set your inputs to width: 50%; or you may choose any other combination targeting each input specifically.

```
 #div2 {
         display: block;
         margin: 0 auto;
         width: 100%;
         white-space: nowrap;
    }

input {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 50%;
    }
```

If you want the input to be 80% and the button to be 20% you need to target them individually with your classes.

```
.form-control {
             display: inline-block;
             width: 80%;
             margin: 0;
             padding: 0;
        }

 .btn-primary {
             width: 20%;
             margin: 0 auto;
             padding: 0;
 }
```

([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gpp5vp32/1/)) Updated

Comment: on your example there needs to be more css because if you set the input width to 80% then the submit button goes off the screen

Comment: Please check my revised answer and let me know if this fixes your problem.